# How to focus at several locations at once?

Tags: nikon, focus

I've seen pictures with several objects being in focus and others not in focus. How do I do that? When I focus my camera, lets say along a wall, only parts of the wall will be in focus.

Here is a picture that will help illustrate what I mean, the other picture shows how I would want the camera to focus:

[image]
[image]

Comment: As per my answer, I would suggest that is not a duplicate, as this question specifically asks how to maintain the entire wall in focus while other objects are not in focus.

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35371/can-focus-stacking-produce-the-same-effect-as-tilt-shift

Answer (score 4):

Because your question mentions keeping other areas of the photo out-of-focus, I assume you've considered and rejected the possibility of a smaller aperture to increase depth of field. If that is not the case, the question posted in the comments as a possible duplicate is an excellent resource.

---

To achieve the effect you're looking for, one option is to use a camera which allows you to tilt the lens relative to the focal plane. This can be done with most large-format cameras, a few medium-format cameras, and a few special lenses on 35mm cameras (commonly called perspective-control or tilt-shift lenses).

The principle behind their operation is the [Scheimpflug Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheimpflug_principle). Essentially, when you tilt the plane of the lens, you shift the plane of focus as it appears on your film or sensor. In the case of your example photo, a tilt to the right of the proper amount (properly, a "swing" to the right; tilts are up and down) would bring the plane of focus in line with the wall and you could achieve sharp focus along the wall even with a shallow aperture.

It's a fairly advanced topic to discuss, but it becomes intuitive when explored hands-on with the appropriate equipment.

As your original question is tagged Nikon, I assume you'd be looking for Nikon lenses. To my knowledge, Nikon offers three lenses that allow for movements:

- 24mm f/3.5 PC-E
- 45mm f/2.8 PC-E
- 85mm f/2.8 PC-E Micro

All three are excellent lenses, but not inexpensive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

They were indeed very expensive. I don't think I will ever afford one. So I guess I will never be able to achieve this effect. So the only solution I have is using a smaller aperture.

Comment: You might also consider a lensbaby solution. It's much cheaper. Image quality generally sucks (so does the Holga's but a lot of people like the effect) but you can replicate a tilt/shift look. See http://lensbaby.com/usa/spark.php for info...

Comment: @Chris: If you really wanted to get everything in focus, you could get a used 4x5 system with lens and film holders for ~$500.  The image quality would be astonishing, but you would pay upwards of $10 per shot exposed and developed, and that's not even getting your shots scanned or printed.

Answer (score 4):

You might also consider focus stacking.  While I have no experience myself, there is a [pretty clear article at DPS](http://digital-photography-school.com/an-introduction-to-focus-stacking/).

With regard to using focus stacking to similate the effects of a tilt lens, please see [Can Focus Stacking produce the same effect as Tilt-Shift?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35371/can-focus-stacking-produce-the-same-effect-as-tilt-shift)